# how to split number and string in address

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, split, format

i have some code to format address

```
def format_address(address_string):
  house_number = ()
  street_name = ()

  address_string.split()

  for house_number, street_name in enumerate(address_string):
    if address_string[0].isnumeric():
      house_number = address_string

    elif address_string.isalpha():
      street_name = address_string


  return "house number {house_number} on street named {street_name}".format(house_number=house_number, street_name=street_name)

print(format_address("123 Main Street"))
print(format_address("1001 1st Ave"))
print(format_address("55 North Center Drive"))
```

desire output should be:
house number 123 on street named Main Street

my output:
house number 123 Main Street on street named t

what i'm missing here.Please help

Comment: `address_string.split()` does not change or replace what `address_string` contains, and assigning back to the loop variables `house_number` and `street_name` is also not going to do what you want, and also I have *no idea* what you expect `enumerate` to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
def format_address(address_string):

    house_number, street_name = address_string.split(' ', 1)

    return f"house number {house_number} on street named {street_name}"

print(format_address("123 Main Street"))
print(format_address("1001 1st Ave"))
print(format_address("55 North Center Drive"))
```

Output:

```
house number 123 on street named Main Street
house number 1001 on street named 1st Ave
house number 55 on street named North Center Drive
```

Comment: Nice use of the second argument to `split()`!  However, I would replace your three assignment statements with: `house_number, street_name = address_string.split(' ', 1)` as there is no need to see the ugly `list` underpinnings.

Answer (score 0):

```
address_string.split()
```

This means: create a *new* list with the words from `address_string`, and then *ignore it*. `address_string` is *not changed*. You need to give the result of this `.split()` call its own name. Just like how if you write `3 + 4`, the value of `3` does not change, and the resulting `7` is only useful if you *do something* with it.

```
for house_number, street_name in enumerate(address_string):
```

This means: each time through the loop, `house_number` becomes a number *starting at zero and counting upward*, and `street_name` becomes the next *letter* in the `address_string` (because we are still working with the original string).

```
if address_string[0].isnumeric():
    house_number = address_string
```

This means: each time through the loop, `house_number` will be replaced with the *entire* `address_string`, if the *first character in `address_string`* is numeric. `address_string` never changes, so this comparison always has the same result. A string like `"123 Main Street"` starts with `"1"`, which is numeric, so the `house_number` becomes the entire string `"123 Main Street"`.

Each time through the loop, `house_number` gets replaced by the `for` loop condition, and then again in this `if`. In general, you don't want to assign to your loop variables; it's not very helpful, since they'll keep getting re-assigned by the loop.

```
elif address_string.isalpha():
  street_name = address_string
```

Since the `if` condition is met, this `elif` is never tested.

---

To solve the problem, you must think clearly. What do you want to iterate over? What is a good name to use for those things? What is the rule that tells you whether that thing should be used for the `house_number`? What is the rule that tells you whether that thing should be used for the `address_string`? Then make sure that the tests you use make sense - are you testing the value that you actually want to use? Are you assigning it in the right place?

Answer (score 0):

As Karl says in his answer To solve the problem, you must think clearly.

Just a simple pointer. In the case that the number is always the first element, I would do something simple as this:

split the string in the " " (space character) and the first element is the number, the remainder denoted by the `*` element is a list called `street_name_as_list`, then. the street_name is joining all the words in this list with spaces

```
def format_address(address_string):
  house_number = ()
  street_name = ()

  house_number, *street_name_as_list = address_string.split(" ")
  street_name = " ".join(street_name_as_list)

  return "house number {house_number} on street named {street_name}".format(house_number=house_number, street_name=street_name)

print(format_address("123 Main Street"))
print(format_address("1001 1st Ave"))
print(format_address("55 North Center Drive"))
```

then you can add any verifications for house_number or street_name, and no need to use a loop through the string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to capture the 3 parts.

`'^([0-9]*)(.*)({"|".join(way)})[.]?$'`

This simple expression does the trick. Each part that is contained in parens will be returned as a group in the regex match. You have 3 parts so I made 3 groups. The third group is compiled from an array of "all possible road types" and their initials. When the match is performed the third group is compared against our list, and with the help of modulus we convert the match number to fit the range of way_flat. This way no matter which version the user inputs we can always get the 'full-word' version of the road type. It's just a bonus. Instead of `.. on street named Main Street` you get `.. on street named Main` or maybe more illustratively ~ `..on boulevard named Fairbanks Manor`.

## Example

```
import re
from typing import Pattern

way_flat = ('street', 'road', 'highway', 'parkway', 'avenue', 'boulevard')
way_init = ('st', 'rd', 'hwy', 'pkwy', 'ave', 'blvd')
way      = [*way_flat, *way_init]
way_len  = len(way_flat)

addr_filter: Pattern = re.compile(f'^([0-9]*)(.*)({"|".join(way)})[.]?$', re.I | re.M)

def format_address(addr: str) -> str:
    if m := addr_filter.match(addr):
        w = m.group(3).lower()
        for i, n in enumerate(way):
            if w == n:
                return f'House number {m.group(1)} on {way_flat[i%way_len]} named {m.group(2).strip()}'
        # fallback
        return f'House number {m.group(1)} on {w} named {m.group(2).strip()}'

    raise ValueError(f'Not An Address: {addr} is not a valid address')
        
try:
    print(format_address('123 Main St'))
    print(format_address('1 Fairbanks Manor Blvd'))
    print(format_address('8544 Onda highway'))
except ValueError as err:
    #do something
    pass

#House number 123 on street named Main
#House number 1 on boulevard named Fairbanks Manor
#House number 8544 on highway named Onda
```